# How to extract Field History for a Custom Object

Tags: data-loader, data

In dataloader, there's no `CustomObject__History` object when clicking "Show All Objects". Can FH for a custom object be extracted somehow?

My object is on the detail side of an MD relationship, so reporting is not implemented.

UPDATE:
The object **is** in the dataloader list - it's called `History: <Your Custom Obj>`, you have to be smart enough to scroll to the letter "H". However, the export doesn't work. Using SOAP I get "Your query request was running for too long", using Bulk - "Server error returned in unknown format". I have around 5M records in the object itself

Comment: Are you sure, that Field History Tracking is enabled for your `CustomObject__c` ?

Comment: Also, last time I used Data Loader, I recall having check a box to show all objects.

Comment: @OleksandrBerehovskyi yes, it is enabled. I can see field history in the related list and can query for them (in theory; in practice due to the volume such queries are timed out every time)

Comment: @sfdcfox yeah, I clicked it and mentioned it in the question :) The list has all the standard object histories like ContactHistory, but none for the custom objects.

Comment: @AlCher, Data loader settings, can you Uncheck "Use Bulk API" and try?

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi it's the same with both Bulk and SOAP

Comment: @AlCher, Can you check in work bench https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php

Comment: I tried exporting field history on custom object using dataloader just now. It worked just fine (1) Can you check which version of dataloader you are on and try to update it first? (I used version 53.0.2) (2) This [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.when_to_use_the_data_loader.htm&type=5) suggest to work with Salesforce support when you are dealing with more than 5 million records, although I'm not sure if that was meant just for importing. May be your problem is due to too many records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object is in the dataloader list - it's called History: , you have to be smart enough to scroll to the letter "H". However, the export doesn't work. Using SOAP I get "Your query request was running for too long", using Bulk - "Server error returned in unknown format". I have around 5M records in the object itself